# Why can Kotlin's code directly call the top level function from “kotlin.collections”, without import the package

Tags: kotlin

Why can Kotlin's code directly call the top level function from “kotlin.collections”, without import the package. such as below function `listOf`:

```
data class Person1(val name: String, val age: Int)

class DataClassExecutor {
  ... ...
  fun test(arg: String?): String? {
    val persons = listOf(
        Person1("Lucy", age = 26), 
        Person1("Lily", age = 29))
    ... ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please refer this page: https://kotlinlang.org/spec/packages-and-imports.html. It says:

> There are some packages which have all their entities implicitly
> imported into any Kotlin file, meaning one can access such entity
> without explicitly using import directives.

The List includes `kotlin.collections`.

This is similar to how in Java, `java.lang` is implicitly imported. In Java one does not need to say `java.lang.System.out.println`, just `System.out.println` is enough.